# Rspec model associations

Tags: rspec, associations

I cann't pass rspec test

spec/models/ticket_spec.rb

```
describe Ticket do
  describe "should have associations" do
    it { should belong_to(:location) }
```

bash

```
  1) Ticket should have associations 
     Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:location) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `relations' for #<Class:0x000000076a34a0>
     # ./spec/models/ticket_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

models/ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base 
  ...
  belongs_to :location
```

Gemfile

```
group :test do
  ...
  gem "shoulda"
  gem "shoulda-matchers"
end
```

Comment: Just to make sure, does the location have a ticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using subject feature, you should define that subject:

```
before { @ticket = ... }
subject { @ticket }
```

and then you can use it as:

```
it { should belong_to(:location) }
```

Comment: Yes, I use `before { @tt = Factory.create(:ticket) }` and where I must palce `subject { @ticket }`?

Comment: Right before you're using it { should }, don't muss up '@tt' and '@ticket'.

Comment: I don't know why your first example was failing, but the explicit `subject` should not be needed here. `describe Ticket` sets the implicit subject to a new instance of `Ticket`.

Comment: How implicit subject can set the relation with another object?